# How to replace a character in a String^ at an index in C++ in .net CLR application?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli

I have a String^ variable. It's a string, I would like to replace a character at ith position in it. I have seen C# examples where they use StringBuilder. What will work for C++ ?

I am using VS 2012 on Windows 7.

Comment: This is some funky dialect of C++?

Comment: Yup! to make string classes in .net compatible with C++ and garbage collection. They have added a lot of stuff!

there is a keyword called gcnew as well.

I am using this for the first time!
I know C# and I know regular C++ but this is weird for me.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar- Did you mean `String^` ?

Comment: You cannot, the content of `System::String` is immutable. Just construct a new one with [`System::String::Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx).

Comment: Have you tried using `StringBuilder`? There is nothing C# specific about it. Adding some `^` after reference types and using `gcnew` instead of `new` should do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot modify the existing System::String, its content is immutable. But you can easily construct a new one with [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) the same way as in C#:

```
String^ s = "abcd";
auto sb = gcnew System::Text::StringBuilder(s);
sb[2] = 'C';
s = sb->ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str="abcdefgh";

    str[2] = 'x';

    cout<<str<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You can find your answer in this sample code.

Comment: Isn't that `std::string` not .net's `System.String`? So I don't think it applies to the OP's question.